# Can we safely access user-mode buffer passed as argument in syscalls, or do we need to use copy_from_user? (Linux)

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module, wdk

Let's assume I'm hooking a syscall such as openat in Linux using an LKM. Now coming from a Windows driver development world, i have two questions:

1. Considering that the file path is passed as an argument in openat, Can we safely directly access that buffer (read or write), which is a user-mode address, without using copy_from_user? Because in Windows, certain callbacks are guaranteed to be called at the context of the calling process, thus we can safely assume that the buffer address is correct and not for another context, and even if they are not in the same context, we can attach to the calling process.
2. In Windows, there is a concept of paged out memory and IRQL, which means that on callbacks that have IRQL of DISPATCH or above, we cannot access memory that is paged out. Is there a similar concept in Linux? For example what happens if the user-mode address is paged out and i try to access it? Can i catch the exception? In Windows we can catch the exception for accessing invalid user-mode addresses, but invalid kernel-mode address access cannot be caught and it causes a BSOD.

I'm asking this because i need to hook opennat to monitor some file opens, but the problem is that if i try to allocate a kernel buffer and then use copy_from_user to get the file path, this will take a lot of time, but if i can somehow safely access the user-mode buffer directly without any copy and read or write to it, this will save up a lot of time. In Windows, even if the context is invalid, we can still attach to that process, lock the user-mode buffer with the help of MDL, and read/write to it, but I'm not sure if this is possible in Linux or not.

Comment: It is possible to pin user pages in memory (which may fault the pages in) (e.g. using `pin_user_pages_fast()` and then temporarily map them to kernel virtual addresses (e.g. using `kmap_atomic()`), but all that seems like overkill for accessing a pathname. There are functions specifically for getting a filename from userspace: `getname()` and `getname_flags()`.

Comment: The special functions simply wrap `strncpy_from_user` with some extra fiddling, so the answer to OPs question is "yes". :-)

Comment: @IanAbbott So can i access the buffer of a user-mode address which was given to me via an argument directly in any syscall and read/write to it without doing any extra work? Thus there is no need for copy_from_user? Do the functions you mentioned copy from user or just make the buffer address accessible?

Comment: @oakad but if that is just copying from user-mode address then that defeats the whole purpose, I'm trying to not do an extra copy and just directly access user-mode buffer from a syscall and read/write to it.

Comment: `getname()` functions use reference-counted, cached data structures, allocating them if not currently cached, but use `strncpy_from_user()` to do the actual copy from the userspace address, like `copy_from_user()`. If you are writing a hook wrapper around the openat syscall handler, the real function will probably get the same cached data structure as the wrapper unless you change the filename in the wrapper.

Comment: But if it is not cached then we still have the same problem, and that still doesn't even solve the problem of accessing the process address space directly. In Windows we can easily do it  by locking the virtual memory and access it with the help of MDLs. I assume this is what   pin_user_pages_fast + kmap_atomic is doing right? And do i still need to use these two in case the calling process is in the same context as we are (which i assume is the case with syscalls) ?

Comment: The user space can (and should) be able to be mapped out at any time.  Pinning all sorts of user processes to memory is going to be a disaster.  Either use `strncpy_from_user()` or wait for the file to open and you can used the name from the returned file structures.  It is not clear what you are doing with the file names and what kind of longevity you expect.  User space tasks can be killed at any time.  Importantly, `strncpy_from_user()` handles a process being killed while you are trying to record the filename.  The solution your looking for is a DOS attack in the making.

Comment: @artlessnoise So what happens in Linux when 1. LKM tries to read invalid user memory 2. LKM tries to read invalid kernel memory? Can any of the exceptions be caught, or they both cause panic?

Comment: `strncpy_from_user()` uses translated instructions (using user space MMU) and on a fault it will return an error.  The fault is caught by the kernel and no panic occurs.  If the LKM is reading invalid memory generically, it will panic.  Special 'read from user' code is trapped with the fault handlers to return if an error occurs during the routines, such as `strncpy_from_user()`.